# Create form with replaceWith() function in Jquery, But unable to validate using jquery validation Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have created html page and it has empty division tag, using jquery i can replace form in empty div tag. these steps are working properly. but when try validate form which was created previously using replaceWith()function, not supported at all. i used jquery validation plugin for validation process, codes are below.

Jquery replace function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add_new_parent").click(function () {
        $("#family_page_body").replaceWith("<form name='add-parent' id='add-parent' action='#' method='post'>
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-md-4'> <label for='nic'>NIC Number :</label>
 </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-md-4'>
<input type='text' name='txt_nic' style='height: 35px;' class='form-control' id='txt_nic' autocomplete='off' placeholder='Enter your NIC Number'>
</div></div></form>");
});
});
```

Jquery Validation Codes

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("nic_validator", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[V-V0-9]+$/.test(value);
}, "Invalid NIC Number");
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add-parent").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
         var form_data = $("#add-parent").serialize(); 
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                url: "../svr/add-parent.php",
                data: form_data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#error").html(data);                   
                }                
            });
        },
        rules: {
            txt_nic:{
                required:true,
            },
            office_contact:{
                maxlength:3,
            },
            messages: {
               txt_nic: {
                   required:"This Field Is Required",
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This is a Html Page

```
<div class="middle-box">
                    <br/>
                    <div id="family_page_body">

                        <br/>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `.validate()` method within a document ready...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add-parent").validate({ ....
```

This is your whole problem.

Your form **does not yet exist** when you call `.validate()` so the validate plugin can not be initialized on it.

You must call the `.validate()` method *after* your form is created.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#add_new_parent").click(function () {

        // FIRST -> create the form
        $("#family_page_body").replaceWith("<form name='add-parent' id='add-parent' action='#' method='post'>....</form>");

        // SECOND -> initialize validation plugin on your new form
        $("#add-parent").validate({
            ....
        });

    });

});
```